# How to update dataframe already stored in cache using python-streamlit library after some dataframe manipulation?

Tags: python, caching, ag-grid, streamlit

I’m relatively new to this awesome tool and would like to understand if it is possible to update the cache value with the new value.

**Background:**
I am developing a tool in python where data is loaded from the SQL database, displayed using Streamlit Ag-Grid, where the user can manipulate the data on the grid, and upon changes, the data should then overwrite the cached data with the new data so that whenever the page is auto-refreshed, “address_frame” takes the last data updated (from the grid) rather than the raw data from the database. Lastly, user has the option to store the data to the database once he’s done with the manipulation.

**Where I need support!**
I would like to understand how to update the cache once I have the updated dataframe.
Right now, even after I assign the updated dataframe to the variable address_frame, it will still contain the cached data that was loaded from the database

Code snippet:

```
@st.experimental_memo(show_spinner=True,suppress_st_warning=True)
def load_Raw_Address():
       with st.spinner('Loading Cleansed Address Data From Database. This may take a while...'):
           query_raw='SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DQ_Raw_Address]'
           address_frame_raw = pd.read_sql(query_raw,con)
       return address_frame_raw

#Assign raw data to address_frame    
address_frame = load_Raw_Address()

#Show on AgGrid, user can manipulate the data on the grid    
grid_return = AgGrid(address_frame, gridoptions ,editable=True ,allow_unsafe_jscode=True,theme = 'balham' , width = "100%", height = "800px")

#manipulated data is ultimately assigned to the address_frame again. 
#NOTE: THIS NEEDS TO REPLACE PREVIOUS CACHED VALUE WITH NEW ONE   
address_frame = grid_return['data']
```

**Actual behavior:**
Currently, If i manipulate the data on the dataframe and refresh the page, the cached data is still stored as raw data from DB and is loaded.

Comment: Be careful with that statement at the top `address_frame = load_Raw_Address()`. When streamlit reruns from top to bottom, that will be executed. Your changes in the frame that is in `grid_return` will be lost, and you will always see the same frame values. You can use a checkbox in streamlit grid, select the row you want to change. Then you can save it to your database directly via selected_rows key of grid_return. When streamlit reruns from top to bottom, your database is now able show an updated data. The `address_frame = load_Raw_Address()` call now contains the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use st.session_state to store the returned data from AgGrid.
See the official guide: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state

By introducing a check if dataframes are equal, you can avoid overwriting the modified df with the originally loaded one.